# Length of normally moved curve

Tags: differential-geometry

Let $\gamma(t)$ be a naturally parametrized plane curve, $k(t)=|\gamma''(t)|$ be its curvature. The ends of normal vectors to $\gamma$ of length $\epsilon$ form a curve $\gamma_\epsilon$, what is its length?

As $\gamma$ is naturally parametrized, $(\gamma',\gamma')=1$, so $(\gamma', \gamma'')=0$, the normal vector is proportional to $y''$ and $\gamma_\epsilon=\gamma + \epsilon \frac{\gamma''}{k}$. The length is $l(\gamma_\epsilon)=\int_\gamma \sqrt{(\gamma_\epsilon', \gamma_\epsilon')} dt$, where $\gamma_\epsilon'$ is a linear combination of $\gamma'$, $\gamma''$ and $\gamma'''$ with coefficients depending on $k$, so its enough to express $(\gamma^{(i)}, \gamma^{(j)})$ via $k$ and its derivatives.

I know that $k(t)$ determines $\gamma(t)$, so I expect it to be possible, but I got stuck with $(\gamma''', \gamma''')$. Could you help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It may be easier to work with $n$, the unit normal, and $n^\prime$. You know that $\langle\gamma^\prime, n \rangle= 0$, so $\langle\gamma^{\prime\prime}, n\rangle = - \langle \gamma^\prime, n^\prime\rangle$. On the other hand, $\langle n, n\rangle =1 $ so $\langle n^\prime, n\rangle = 0$ which means that $n^\prime$ is proportional to $\gamma^\prime$ (in 2 dimensions). The length of $n^\prime$ you get from the previous relation, since you also know that $\gamma^{\prime\prime}$ is proportional to $n$. Now try with $\gamma + \varepsilon n$.